# Will's problem in Good Will Hunting

Tags: good-will-hunting

I am a big fan of this movie. However I did not understand what Will's major problem was? He was a mathematical genius but did not care about academic or financial success. I do get that he was a victim of violence from his childhood and Sean Maguire helps him to overcome his problems. In the end he tells him that "It's not your fault".

I still don't get how did that help him?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like many victims of child abuse, Will Hunting was consumed by shame about what happened to him, and to avoid painful reminders of the shame, he used defensive techniques such as underachieving to avoid failure (like with his choice of jobs) and sabotaging relationships to avoid intimacy (like with his girlfriend).

Sean Maguire helped Will begin to move past the shame -- and, presumably, to get more out of life.

Comment: That makes sense. Sean convinced Will to stop blaming himself for everything bad happened to him.